# Gradle task failing from Android Studio, Wrapper working fine

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, task

I have a project with multiple modules and have add the following task, I have made it simple here but it does more.

When I run using ./gradlew modulename:assemblePush from the terminal it works fine.

However when I locate the task from the gradle pane (module -> tasks -> Other -> assemblePush) in Android Studio the build script fails with:

> What went wrong:
>
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':assemblePush'.
> Task with path 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'moudleName'.**

```
allprojects {
    task assemblePush(dependsOn: ['assembleRelease']) {
        doLast {
       println name
       println project.name
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to sub projects has worked, this can now be called by Android Studio

```
subprojects {
    task assemblePush(dependsOn: ['assembleRelease']) {
        doLast {
       println name
       println project.name
       }
   }
}
```